# Using SQL instruction in CSV file in Python Code

Tags: python, sql, csv

I have 4 files A.csv, B.csv, C.csv, D.csv, which I assume can be considered as table in Database. Now is there a way I can use SQL commands in Python to perform SQL  instructions to get data?

There is SQlLite but it uses `.db` file extension (e.g. `con = lite.connect('system.db')`), not `.csv`, so I don't know how use it. Also there is  [csvquerytool](https://pypi.org/project/csvquerytool/).

but the code given in the page does explain how in python SQL instruction needs to be provided.

Which libraries are required? please provide an example, if possible.

Comment: It seems to me that it would be much easier to simply convert those csv files into an actual database and perform whatever you need to with it, rather than emulating database behavior. Also, you might want to consider taking a look at pandas. It is an excellent package that provides many tools to work with data and is able to read and write csv and pandas + sqlalchemy work flawlessly for databases as well.

Comment: @KarlOlufsen I want to practise SQL instruction in Python without installing SQL software ...

Comment: Then you should really look into sqlalchemy package. It provides you with full power of SQL from inside the python in a form of pythonic objects. You can use it without actually interfacing with the database, however if you want to, it provides you with tools for that as well.